# lift list of values to a list of lists of values

Tags: python

Here's a tricky one.  I want to take a list of integers, and turn it into a list of lists containing that integer.  This is so that I can later append to that list.  Unfortunately `list()` does not take a single integer, so I can't `map` it to the list.

Here's a more concrete explanation:

Given,

```
>>> a = range(5)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How can I elegantly turn it into,

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

I tried `map`'ing `list`:

```
>>> map(list,a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Same thing with `tuple`.  In fact ideally I'd be able to map the tuple or list operators, but of course that doesn't work with Python's syntax:

```
>>> map((,),a)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    map((,),a)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So the only way I can come up with a solution is to define my own list constructor:

```
>>> L = lambda x: [x]
>>> map(L,a)
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

That works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a more Pythonic solution.  Mostly I was just surprised to discover that `list(3)` does not give `[3]`.

Comment: The `list` constructor turns an iterable into a list. What's surprising about that? Python's lists aren't linked lists.

Answer (score 9):

I'd use a list comprehension for this:

```
In [1]: a = range(5)

In [2]: [[v] for v in a]
Out[2]: [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general way to turn scalars into either lists or tuple, you can first turn them into a generic iterable returning one value (the scalar), and then construct either a list or tuple from that using the normal constructor:

```
def iterone(scalar):
    yield scalar

scalars = range(5)
iterables = map(iterone, scalars)
lists = map(list, iterables)
tuples = map(tuple, map(iterone, scalars))
```

Although @aix's versions *looks* more pythonic to me.

Note this behaves a little oddly though: applying `map` to `iterables` *advances* each iterator here, so you can't use it a second time.  That's why `tuples` just re-creates it directly, and in fact assigning the list of iterables name at all is probably error prone.